# Get value of input where checkbox[] is checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I've a problem, i need to get a value of an input (text) when his checkbox is selected.

```
<form method=GET>

<input type =checkbox name = checkbox[]>
<input type = 'text' name=? >

<input type =checkbox name = checkbox[]>
<input type ='text' name=? >

<input type =checkbox name = checkbox[]>
<input type = 'text' name=? >

<input type = 'submit' name='Submit' >

</form>
```

This is what I want excactly

```
If(checkbox == checked)
{
Echo the entered input text value
}
```

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you meant after submission to a PHP script.
I just threw this together and have not tested it yet, but looks fairly straight forward.

It will also work with `<input type=checkbox name="c[]">`, but just a little apprehensive about the text and checkbox synchronization with the array.

### HTML

```
<form action="./chkbx.php" method=GET>
<input type=checkbox name="c1" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="t1" />
<input type=checkbox name="c2" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="t2" />
<input type=checkbox name="c3" value="3"/>
<input type="text" name="t3" >
<input type="submit" name='Submit' />
</form>
```

### PHP

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val){
  $chk[substr($key,0,1)] = intval(substr($key,1,1));
  $txt[substr($key,0,1)][intval(substr($key,1,1))] = $val;
}
echo '<h2>Text=' .  $txt['t'][$chk['c']] . '<h2>';
```

### Test Code

```
<?php
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Menu Test</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
</style></head><body>

<form action="./chkbx.php" method=GET>
<input type=checkbox name="c1" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="t1" />
<input type=checkbox name="c2" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="t2" />
<input type=checkbox name="c3" value="3"/>
<input type="text" name="t3" >
<input type="submit" name='Submit' />
</form>
EOT;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val){
  $chk[substr($key,0,1)] = intval(substr($key,1,1));
  $txt[substr($key,0,1)][intval(substr($key,1,1))] = $val;
}
echo '<h2>' .  $txt['t'][$chk['c']] . '<h2>';
echo '<pre>';
var_export($chk);
echo"-------------------\n";
var_export($txt);
echo '</pre></body></html>';
```

### Results:

With checkbox c2 checked and text boxes containing "Text One" "Text Two" "Text Three"

[image: Test Page]

Below output from is the `echo '<h2>Text=' .  $txt['t'][$chk['c']] . '<h2>';`

### Text Two

```
$chk (
  't' => 3,
  'c' => 2,
  'S' => 0,
)-------------------
$txt (
  't' => 
  array (
    1 => 'Text One',
    2 => 'Text Two',
    3 => 'Text Three',
  ),
  'c' => 
  array (
    2 => '2',
  ),
  'S' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Submit',
  ),
)
```

### Summary:

The submitted check box value is stored in `$chk['c']`
The submitted Text is in `$txt['t'][0],  $txt['t'][2],  $txt['t'][3]` respectfully.

So the text can be retrieved by `$txt['t'][$chk['c']`

Loop and echo executed in **0.000054 seconds.**  54 micro seconds, not too bad.

Comment: But I get the checkbox values from the database? I can't use n1, n2

Comment: It will put the text value into  $text.  If checkbox  "c1" is checked $text will have the value of text input  "t1".  I'll post the results of my testing.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox and radio type field does not get submit when they are not checked or selected.

So you need to check the get/request object whether checkbox name is there or not in the object.

Like

```
if(isset($_GET['checkbox'])){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you check `checkbox` you can get value of next input box.

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
       alert($(this).next("input").val());
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/za922y9n/)

Comment: Thanks for your questions, but my question isn't to get the checkbox value, or when it checked, I use there a foreach loop. I want to get the next input text value of the checked checkbox with PHP

Answer (score 0):

The value of checkbox only returns boolean (i.e. true of false).
You should use

```
if(isset($_GET["checkbox"]))
```

instead of

```
if(checkbox == checked)
```